# Grep pipe support and how to filter grep results

Tags: grep

I try to filter the output of `M-x grep` with `grep --color=always -nH -e "text_to_find" ~/path/to/files/*.org | grep -v "text_to_ignore"` but it doesn't seem to be working. The 'to be ignored' part is still not filtered away.

Is it true that `grep` in Emacs do not support piping? If so, how do we filter `grep` results?

Comment: `grep` in Emacs is just `grep`. It's whatever OS `grep` you have. There is an Emacs command `grep`, but it just invokes your OS `grep` (and gives you nice access to the results etc.).

Comment: I assume `grep` command doesn't invoke a shell, so things like in it won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the first grep `grep --color=always -nH -e "text_to_find" ~/path/to/files/*.org` puts escape sequences around matches for `text_to_find` to colorize those matches.

If the second search string `text_to_ignore` contains `text_to_find`. Matches of `text_to_ignore` in the original files are not found in the output of the first `grep` call because of those escape sequences.

Leave the `--color=always` option out to avoid that effect. The matches of `text_to_find` are no longer highlighted with yellow color but the second grep works if `text_to_find` is part of `text_to_ignore`.

If you really need to colorize the matches for `text_to_find` you can colorize them as a last step:

```
grep -nH -e "text_to_find" ~/path/to/files/*.org | grep -v "text_to_ignore | grep --color=always -e "text_to_find""
```

Answer (score 4):

What you were attempting with a pipe works fine for me (tested in 26.1 and 25.3).

- Which version are you using?
- Does your command work *outside* of Emacs?

*Edit*: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `grep-use-null-device` might mess up your command, by preventing the second grep from reading stdin.  This would be apparent in the command line displayed in the grep buffer.  If this is the issue, then hopefully you can simply disable that option via the customize interface.

---

Failing that, you can always filter the results after the fact with the `flush-lines` and `keep-lines` commands, after toggling the read-only state with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd>.

Personally I like/use the [winnow](https://github.com/dgtized/winnow.el) library for streamlining that:

Use <kbd>x</kbd> to remove lines matching a pattern, or <kbd>m</kbd> to keep only the lines matching a pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

The [elgrep library](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep) allows searching files without external programs and with user-defined search function.

The command <kbd>M-x</kbd> `elgrep-menu` -- also available as menu item `Tools` -> `Search Files (elgrep)...` -- provides an input field `Search Function`.

The following search function searches for the given regular expression `text` but ignores lines that match `text_to_ignore`.

```
(lambda (re &rest _) (and (re-search-forward re nil t) (null (string-match-p "text_to_ignore" (thing-at-point 'line)))))
```

Remarks:

- `elgrep` only checks whether the return value of the search function is non-nil
- it evaluates the match data after a successful return of the search function
- `string-match-p` preserves the match data
- `(thing-at-point 'line)` uses `forward-line` and therefore does also not change the match data

The following image shows the full dialog of `elgrep-menu`.

[image: Ignoring text with elgrep]

Answer (score 1):

The elgrep library has evolved. So there is now a better alternative way to search for lines matching `text_to_find` but not matching `text_to_ignore`. One does no longer need to explicitly input Elisp functions.

One can define records of a file, and specify a regular expression that must not match in a record to be considered in the search for another regular expression. Full lines are an example for records.

Settings for your usecase in the `elgrep-menu` (`Tools` → `Search Files (Elgrep)...`):

- Set `Expression` to `List of regexps`
- Input `text_to_find` as first regexp
- Input `!text_to_ignore` as second regexp Note, that the leading `!` negates the expression. The negated expression must not match within the record.
- Input the directory and the file name regexp. Note that you can use completion for the input of the directory. Furthermore resetting the elgrep menu sets the directory to the directory of the last visited file.
- Set `Beginning of Record` to `Regexp` and use `^` as regexp standing for `beginning-of-line`.
- Set `End of Record` to `Regexp` and use `$` as regexp standing for `end-of-line`.

Note that this method can be inefficient for very large files with many lines (order of 100MB with 100 Mio lines) with only few matches for `text_to_find` because each line is searched for the regexps.